# Launching an option menu from ListView in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

First of all I'm new in Programming Android and in StackOverflow!!

I've created a ListView dynamicaly, I mean, I load the list with lines from a file.

Now, what I want to do is to launch a menu, like options menu,when an item has been clicked.

I searched and the easy way is by using the inflate method however it uses a menu as argument.
However I've set up a listener with OnItemClick which uses as argument an AdapterView, a View arg1, a int arg2, and a long arg3, but I a need a menu to the inflate method ... :S

here's the code for mainactivity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.menu);

   ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

   func = getTurmas();
   list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, func));

   list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()  {  

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                //System.out.println("teste");
                MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_showup, null);
               //my problem is here,instead of NULL I should put a menu, but how?

            }  
          });        
}
```

Note: In menu folder I have my menu created with 3 items

Thanks in advance for any help

Best Regards,

Karloz

Answer (score 0):

**Creating `ContextMenu` will do you work in a best way of setting menu to `listView`**

***This should do the trick. Don't forget to: registerForContextMenu(lvUsers);***

```
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
func=getTurmas();
list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,func));
registerForContextMenu(list);

public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
switch (item.getItemId())
 {
 case R.id.edit:
 editNote(info.id);
 return true;
 case R.id.delete:
 deleteNote(info.id);
 return true;
 default:
 return true;     
 }
 return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

---

**res/menu/context_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/edit"
      android:title="@string/edit" />
<item android:id="@+id/delete"
      android:title="@string/delete" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Hi Vikalp Patel!

Thank you for your answer!

I got what u explained and I implemented it.

However it didnt work.

The first 3 lines you suggest in your code, I put in the method OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) of activity. Is that correct?

and the 2nd line, when I set the adapter, I had to change to 
list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, func));

because when I put your line it tells me " Cannot instantiate the type ListAdapter" even after I import List.adapter class.


Do you have any idea why its going like this?

BR

Karloz

Comment: @karloz.smith Hope you've get `ArrayList-via getTurmas() into func`very correctly.

Comment: @karloz.smith I've edited the code please go through it. Try to double check your `func=getTurmas()` whether it's returning `Array` or not?. Also try these to just check the code whether it's working or not.`String[] func = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
  "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
  "Linux", "OS/2" };`.`Comment out your func=getTurmas() at time of testing`